# Force iOS to recalculate needed window size for sliding menu

Tags: ios, css, mobile

So I've seen this issue with mobile browsers before and usually just ignored it. When you have an element, (I don't believe it matters how it is positioned) and move it off the viewable area, the mobile browser (in my test case safari) adds the ability to scroll over to it. I am making a slide out menu pretty much the same as on mashable.com's website. Basically the menu is z-indexed behind the main content. On tapping the menu button the main content does a CSS translate to the right to reveal the menu. However, after it slides back, iOS "remembers" that there was an element off the screen and still allows the user to scroll over to the right, even though nothing is there any more.

Is there a way (I would assume via javascript) to force mobile browsers to recalculate the viewable area, or where the elements are. Some event I could fire or something. I can't for the life of me Google my way out of this one. The menu is working as it should. My current "fix" is to prevent the default behavior of the swipe-left event on touch move. However using this method it may prevent me from doing other things I have planned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting the content to 99.9% width and just after a few milliseconds remove the width again.

```
// on closing menu:
if(panel==='closing'){
    $("#content").css('width','99.9%');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#content").css('width','');
    },100);
}
```

Comment: Went a different route... ended up not checking.